# select box options are on DOM but not showing on bootstrap-select dropdown ul in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-select

The problem is I need to get the data using axios into select box option .
so it looks like this.

```
<optgroup label="group1">
  <option v-for="aa11 in aa11" :value="aa11.value" :key="aa11.code">{{aa11.value}}</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="group2">
  <option v-for="aa12 in aa12" :value="aa12.value" :key="aa12.code">{{aa12.value}}</option>
</optgroup>
```

and the data is set like this.

```
data(){
  return{
    aa11:[],
    aa12:[]
  }
}
```

and on js

```
axios.get('URL')
    .then(response=>{
         if(response.data.upjongapi[0].aa11 != null){
   for(let i=0; i<response.data.upjongapi[0].aa11.length; i++){
 this.aa11.push({"code":response.data.upjongapi[0].aa11[i].code,"value":response.data.upjongapi[0].aa11[i].value});
            }
        }
```

So, it mounts on the DOM, I can see in on chrome dev tool.
but I want to use bootstrap-select which I downloaded and customize.
(I import it instead of npm install.)

The problem is on bootstrap-select DOM which is dropdown `ul`, in `li` it doesn't show.
sometimes it shows, so I can't figure out when it shows or when it doesn't show.
(seems like it depends on the luck =( )

[this is the problem capture pic. the options that are in yellow circle should be on select box!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnSKi.png)

I want to see all the options, and it all mounted on DOM, but i dont' think it mounted on bootstrap-select dropdown.
What can I do?

Comment: your "alias" and "source data" in v-for should have different name like: v-for="item in items"

Comment: thanks for the reply! but i tried, it didn't work =(

Answer (score 0):

To future readers,

```
    updated() {
       $(this.$el).find('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
```

this worked like a charm =)
and here is the page i read
https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/397